# How to check if a word is single or multi and to dived in 2 array in php

Tags: php, regex, conditional-statements

I have to check a array of string data .

For example this is the string :

```
$keywords="today, tomorroy, world, is a good day , a good day is, today"
```

I have to check if is single word or multi word.

If is multi word i have to order and leave only one for example : is a good day ; a good day is  i have to leave only : is a good day  . This words i have to store in other array.

In the end i have to have only this results:

This is my code:

```
     $keywords = "";          
     $singleword="";
     $multiword="";

     foreach ($response->getResults() as $result) {                
            $keywords .= $result->getText()->getValue() . ",";

            if(count(explode(' ', $keywords)) > 1) {
                $multiword++;                                                  
            }
            $singleword++;                                  
       }    
      return $keywordsgenerated;
```

I need to return : today, tomorroy, world, is a good day 
Please can you help me to fix , i'm new in php.

**EDIT**

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you mean. At first you want to divde your keywords-string into an array based by commas so array will be [0] today, [1] tomorroy, [2] world, is a good day , [3] a good day is, [4] today and then from that array remove duplicates?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld can you help me please with some code ?

Comment: I would like to get an answer on my question before I am able to try to help you :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld yes,I want to remove dublicate in single words like today to return just one time and in the multiword to remove phrase with the same word inside and to let just one of them for example : world, is a good day

Comment: Aha. So in your example you want remove today (because it is a single word that exists once), but also "multi-words" like "is a good day" because the same words exists but in another order and is therefore threated as a dublicate as well. So you would the string:$keywords="today, tomorroy, world, is a good day " . Is that correct?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld i want to show just once . $keywords="today, tomorroy, world, is a good day , a good day is, today"  to show like :  $keywords="today, tomorroy, world, a good day is"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were looking for something like this:

```
<?php
$keywords="today, tomorrow, world, is a good day , a good day is, today";
$arr = array_unique(explode(",",$keywords));

$words = [];
foreach($arr as $key=>$a) {    
    $words_explode = explode(" ", $a);
    foreach($words_explode as $w) {
        $words[] = $w;
    }        
}
$new_words = array_unique($words);

$result = implode(" ", $new_words);
foreach($arr as $item) {
    $result = str_replace($item,$item.",",$result);
}
$result = trim($result,", ");
var_dump($result);
```

**UPDATE:**

I think? I got what you were looking for?

```
$keywords = "hansgrohe,hansgrohe focus,küchenarmatur,hansgrohe metris";
$arr = explode(',', $keywords);
$already = [];
$result = '';
foreach($arr as $word) {
    $subword = explode(" ", $word);
    foreach($subword as $actual_word) {
        if (!in_array($actual_word, $already)) {
            $result .= $actual_word . ' ';  
            $already[] = $actual_word;      
        }                
    }
}
$result = rtrim($result);

//would result in hansgrohe focus küchenarmatur metris
echo $result;
```

**UPDATE2:**

If you want to know number of occurences of each word.

```
<?php
$keywords = "hansgrohe,hansgrohe focus,küchenarmatur,hansgrohe metris";
$arr = explode(",", $keywords);
$already = [];
$nrwords = [];
$result = '';
foreach($arr as $word) {
    $subword = explode(" ", $word);
    foreach($subword as $actual_word) {
        if (!in_array($actual_word, $already)) {
            $result .= $actual_word . ' ';  
            $already[] = $actual_word;    
            $nrwords[$actual_word] = 0;
        }                
        $nrwords[$actual_word]++;
    }
}
$result = rtrim($result);

//would result in hansgrohe focus küchenarmatur metris
echo $result; 

//would show how many of each word that exists
echo '<pre>';
print_r($nrwords);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: What result did you get?

Comment: just edit my question with real keywords and results

Comment: will be better te check maybe if current keyword exist in the array ? Don't know how ro resolve my case. The problem start when  $result = implode(" ", $new_words); ..because the result is not as should be

Comment: You put my output of previous keywords in your question but that is not interesting. What is your desired output if you have $a = "hansgrohe,hansgrohe focus,küchenarmatur,hansgrohe metris" ?

Comment: sorry you did very well in the first code , the problem is when implode new keyword , new keyword created are sentence with 3-4 words with no sense together

Comment: "will be better te check maybe if current keyword exist in the array ? Don't know how ro resolve my case. The problem start when $result = implode(" ", $new_words); ..because the result is not as should  be". How should it be? It is very unclear what you want.

Comment: No problem! :-)